# Get notified when desktop image changes?

Tags: objective-c, image, macos, cocoa, desktop

Is there any way to get notified when the desktop image changes? The simplest way would be through notifications but I haven't found any for this in particular.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortuantely, there's no way to detect the user's wallpaper or to monitor when it has changed. We simply don't have access to that information.